# ros2- where is the data libopencv-dev

Tags: opencv, library

I want to find this github address.

(I can`t find it,because main opencv`s github has opencv/opencv -b 4,3,2,1)

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what question you are asking. Are you asking how to install opencv on your OS? Please edit your post to tell us which OS and which version of ros2 you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of [libopencv-dev in Ubuntu Jammy is 4.5.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/it/jammy/libopencv-dev). To find the related commit in the `opencv` GitHub project, you've to check the [tags (or releases page on GitHub)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases). There you'll notice the [4.5.4 tag](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.5.4) which is created from [commit 4223495](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/4223495e6cd67011f86b8ecd9be1fa105018f3b1).
This is the source code that is used by the Ubuntu maintainers to create the apt-package (OpenCV even provides a [OpenCVPackaging.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/cmake/OpenCVPackaging.cmake) file).

Comment: Thank you a lot!